# How to hide all clients in all tags in AwesomeWM?

Tags: lua, customization, window-managers, awesome-wm

I am trying to add to my `rc.lua` a function that hides (or minimizes) all clients in all tags in AwesomeWM, just like one can do in Windows with Aero Peek or in GNOME with the ['Show Desktop' extension](https://github.com/l300lvl/Show-Desktop-Button) (as respectively seen on the images):

[image]

[image]

Basically I'm looking for a Lua code snippet, which I think it should look like:

```
awful.key({ modkey }, "l",
                  function ()
                     -- for every client in AwesomeWM...
                     myscreen.client.visible = false,       
                  end
end,
```

Note that this is just a suposition, this code is **not** working. It's a skeleton of what I initially think the answer could be, added for clarifying purposes.

**Technical information:**

```
awesome v4.0-170-g6c24848-dirty (Harder, Better, Faster, Stronger)
 • Compiled against Lua 5.3.3 (running with Lua 5.3)
 • D-Bus support: ✔
 • execinfo support: ✔
 • xcb-randr version: 1.5
 • LGI version: 0.9.2
```

Comment: What's the point of hiding the clients in all tags, why not just the current tag? Also, what do you mean by `hiding`? Minimizing?

Comment: Does "deselect all tags" count as a solution?

Comment: I need to hide (minimize) all of them for a customisation project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some variations of:

```
mouse.screen.selected_tag.selected = false
```

Will work. If you choose to support multiple selected tags, then `for _, t in ipairs(mouse.screen.selected_tags) do t.selected = false end` will be better. If you choose to show the desktop on all screens, then you need to loop them too. You could also save the previously selected tags to be able to restore them when you click on the button twice.

Relevant API doc:

- https://awesomewm.org/apidoc/classes/screen.html#screen.selected_tag
- https://awesomewm.org/apidoc/classes/tag.html#

Answer (score 0):

This will bind super+a to view all tags and super+d to view none:

```
globalkeys = awful.util.table.join( -- for reference
...
awful.key({ modkey,           }, "a",      function ()
                                              local tags = awful.screen.focused().tags
                                              for i = 1, 9 do
                                                tags[i].selected = true
                                              end
                                            end,
          {description="show all tags", group="tag"}),
awful.key({ modkey,           }, "d",      function ()
                                              local tags = awful.screen.focused().tags
                                              for i = 1, 9 do
                                                tags[i].selected = false
                                              end
                                            end,
          {description="show no tags", group="tag"}),
...
```