# awesome-wm: create a shortcut key for toggling view desktop

Tags: awesome-wm

In `awesome` window manager, I want to create a shortcut to `toggle show dekstop` (like `modkey + d`)

I i press `ModKey + d` then it should show destop and again i press `Modkey + d` it should show the windows like previously

Is this possible

Comment: The easiest way might to deselect all tags to show the desktop (but sticky clients (clients visible on all tags) would then still be visible; is this a problem for you?).

Comment: No problem if sticky clients are shown.

Comment: Not much time to test right now, but I think `awful.tag.viewnone(s)` should make the screen visible on screen `s` and `awful.tag.history.restore(s)` should make clients visible again. But I am not totally sure that the restore works and perhaps it needs to be `restore(s, 0)` or `restore(s, 1)` or something like that....

Answer (score 0):

In your `rc.lua` set the following:

```
local show_desktop = false
```

then in `globalkeys = gears.table.join(` add:

```
-- Toggle showing the desktop
awful.key({ altkey, "Control" }, "d",
    function(c)
        if show_desktop then
            for _, c in ipairs(client.get()) do
                c:emit_signal(
                    "request::activate", "key.unminimize", {raise = true}
                )
            end
            show_desktop = false
        else
            for _, c in ipairs(client.get()) do
                c.minimized = true
            end
            show_desktop = true
        end
    end,
    {description = "toggle showing the desktop", group = "client"}),
```

I use ctrl+alt+d but you can replace the above with `awful.key({ modkey }, "d",` if preferred.

Here is a link to my [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/awesomewm/comments/nvz3cn/show_desktop_function/) about this as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I once used to do so (borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47578473/how-to-hide-all-clients-in-all-tags-in-awesomewm)), although I remember it messed up the arrangement of clients/windows:

```lua
awful.key({ M }, "d", function()
    local tags = awful.screen.focused().tags
    for i = 1, 2 do tags[i].selected = false end end,
    create_description("show", "desktop")),

awful.key({ M, S }, "d", function()
    local tags = awful.screen.focused().tags
    for i = 1, 2 do tags[i].selected = true end end,
    create_description("unshow", "desktop")),
```